# How I can derive count(*) from another table using LEFT JOIN mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have table definition like below:

- Place
   (id, name)
- Review
   (id, userid, placeid)
- Favorite 
  (id, userid, placeid)
- Photo
   (id, url, placeid)

  where `placeid` is foreign key to the id of `Place` table.

On that table, I want to derive this kind of information:
`- placeid, place name, totalReview, totalFavorite, totalPhoto.`

I got stucked. My progress currently I can derive information just from 1 table, like I can know totalReview of place, by using this mysql statement:
`SELECT p.*, count(r.id) as totalReview from Place p left join Review r on p.id = r.placeid group by p.id`.
But, I don't know how I can derive the totalFavorite and totalPhoto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to aggregate each table separately.  Here is one solution:

```
SELECT p.*, 
       totalreview, 
       totalfavorite, 
       totalphoto 
FROM   place p 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT placeid, 
                               Count(*) AS totalReview 
                        FROM   review 
                        GROUP  BY placeid) r 
                    ON p.placeid = r.placeid 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT placeid, 
                               Count(*) AS totalFavorite 
                        FROM   favorite 
                        GROUP  BY placeid) f 
                    ON p.placeid = f.placeid 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT placeid, 
                               Count(*) AS totalPhoto 
                        FROM   photo 
                        GROUP  BY placeid) ph 
                    ON p.placeid = ph.placeid
```

Comment: how is the performance by using your solution(LEFT JOIN) vs the Ehsan solution [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10458566/476917)? I don't know that this solution can be solve without LEFT JOIN.

Comment: +1 Yep, thanks for pointing out that my answer was wrong. Don't forget `totalFavorite` and `totalPhoto` in the outer select.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder.  I edited the code to add the two variables.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way to do this:

```
SELECT
p.id, p.name,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Review r WHERE r.placeId=p.id) AS totalReview
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Favorite f WHERE f.placeId=p.id) AS totalFavorite
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Photo ph WHERE ph.placeId=p.id) AS totalPhoto
FROM Place p
```

Comment: It may return records that OP wants but you're not using `LEFT Join`.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know this kind of problem can be solved by using your simple solution :D, and it works! Is this solution more efficient compared to @Gordon Linoff solution above?

Comment: In most databases, the two solutions should produce the same query plan.  I shy away from correlated subqueries for a variety of reasons:  to me, they are less readable; sometimes, they get implemented as nested loop joins; and finally I like for all the tables referenced by a query to be in the from clause.