# MySQL Select from multiple tables ordered by count of left joined table

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have been trying to select data from multiple tables whereas I sort by the count of id's from an additional table that I have joined with a Left Join. Everything works great except for that the count gets incremented with 600something instead of one for each row.

I tried as I saw in a similar problem to put distinct inside the count statement but with the only result of freezing the database.

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `places` (
  `PlaceId` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `AreaId` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`PlaceId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=0;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `places_descriptions` (
  `DescId` int(45) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PlaceId` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(1024) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DescId`),
  KEY `PlaceId` (`PlaceId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=0;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `places_hits` (
  `HitId` int(45) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PlaceId` int(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`HitId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=0;
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    p.PlaceId, 
    p.Name, 
    pd.Description,
    COUNT(ph.HitId) AS numHits
FROM 
    places_descriptions AS pd, 
    places AS p 
    LEFT JOIN places_hits AS ph 
    ON (p.PlaceId = ph.PlaceId) 
WHERE 
    (p.PlaceId = pd.PlaceId) AND 
    (p.AreaId = 1) 
GROUP BY 
    p.PlaceId, 
    p.Name, 
    pd.Description 
ORDER BY 
    numHits DESC, 
    p.PlaceId 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: I couldn't even get this query to run: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88491/1 Please fix the errors?

Comment: Still broken: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88491/4 You can use that SQL Fiddle example to debug if you need to.

Comment: @PaulBellora now it's working based on the first create tables you set up. Sorry and thank you

Comment: Actually, can you post the details for those actual tables? The tables in my SQL Fiddle example were just quick throwaways to get the query running, but they don't actually make sense, for example primary keys referencing each other. Sorry didn't mean to confuse you.

Comment: There it all is, thanks for looking into it

Comment: Haven't been able to look at this closely but I think it might be related to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458534/how-i-can-derive-count-from-another-table-using-left-join-mysql Let me know if that helps or not.

Comment: Yes this will work. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, your problem may be that you're cross-joining pd and p because there's no ON clause.  The placeId=placeId in the where masks this problem by filtering out the rows where the join was inaccurate, but it'd be better to place that condition in the ON.  The large number of rows actually existing before filtering might be throwing off the count, though I'm not sure.

Try this, to start:

```
SELECT 
    p.PlaceId, 
    p.Name, 
    pd.Description,
    COUNT(ph.HitId) AS numHits
FROM 
    places_descriptions AS pd
    INNER JOIN places AS p 
            ON p.PlaceId = pd.PlaceID
    LEFT JOIN places_hits AS ph 
    ON (p.PlaceId = ph.PlaceId) 
WHERE 
    (p.AreaId = 1) 
GROUP BY 
    p.PlaceId, 
    p.Name, 
    pd.Description 
ORDER BY 
    numHits DESC, 
    p.PlaceId
```